# Can I send a SOAP message to a web service without using tool kits like gsoap and get the same result, or is it necessary to use gsoap?

Tags: soap

I mean that if I know the format of message that I want to send, then can I do it manually by sending the message as a string over HTTP without using gsoap and get the same desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem doing it manually. It will even work using just telnet, as long as you use the correct headers and message body.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP is an application layer protocol. So, it will make no difference if you use a tool
or just create and connect a Tcp/Ip socket to the web service endpoint. As long as you
put the right xml with the soap envelope, headers and body it will work well.